# Is it possible to run FFmpeg or some similar library on client-side?

Tags: requirejs, fluent-ffmpeg

I am currently trying to run ffmpeg through fluent-ffmpeg (from node_modules) on the client-side, in a video player application that uses RequireJS. I've looked at https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#2, however this concerns the modules that run on the server side. Is there an option to import/require fluent-ffmpeg or similar library into RequireJS project to run on client side?

This is not working:

```
var FfmpegCommand = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
var command = new FfmpegCommand();
```

Is there an option to import/require fluent-ffmpeg or similar library into RequireJS project to run on client side?

Answer (score 0):

Kagami/ffmpeg.js and videoconverter.js are javascript modules that can be used on the client side via Web Worker.